# After installing EGIT eclipse source editor is not working

Tags: eclipse, egit

Im using eclipse Version: Mars Milestone 1 (4.5.0M1). I have installed EGIT via updatesite. Plugin works now, but i face another issue, that i can not open any of my files in eclipse. That means, i can't open java/etc files in the source editor for development. I see following error log in the eclipse 'view error log' menu.

```
  Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        ... 129 more
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getPreferenceStore()Lorg/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/JavaPlugin, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/JavaPlugin, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore used in the signature
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.ensurePreferenceStoreBackwardsCompatibility(JavaPlugin.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start(JavaPlugin.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
        ... 136 more

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 2 2015-03-11 17:07:34.115
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorActionProvider.
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.actions.CommonActionProviderDescriptor$1.run(CommonActionProviderDescriptor.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.actions.CommonActionProviderDescriptor.createActionProvider(CommonActionProviderDescriptor.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$5.run(NavigatorActionService.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.getActionProviderInstance(NavigatorActionService.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$3.run(NavigatorActionService.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillActionBars(NavigatorActionService.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.selectionChanged(CommonNavigatorManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2171)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1202)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleSelect(CommonViewer.java:478)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1231)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:408)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4985)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5367)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1101)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDownSuper(Tree.java:2044)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1093)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2563)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDown(Tree.java:2012)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5627)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2105)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2329)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5691)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5128)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5277)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui (1156).
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
        at oorg.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1078)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        ... 129 more
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getPreferenceStore()Lorg/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/JavaPlugin, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/JavaPlugin, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore used in the signature
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.ensurePreferenceStoreBackwardsCompatibility(JavaPlugin.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start(JavaPlugin.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
        ... 136 more
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-03-11 17:07:34.116
    !MESSAGE Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorActionProvider.
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui (1156).
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.filters.CommonFilterDescriptor$1.run(CommonFilterDescriptor.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.filters.CommonFilterDescriptor.createFilter(CommonFilterDescriptor.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorFilterService.getViewerFilter(NavigatorFilterService.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorFilterService.getVisibleFilters(NavigatorFilterService.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator.createPartControl(CommonNavigator.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer.createPartControl(ProjectExplorer.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:329)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:547)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1250)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        ... 129 more
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getPreferenceStore()Lorg/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/JavaPlugin, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for resolved class,
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and starting eclipse with the -clean flag fixed it.

For more information refer this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/491168/).